Uncaught TypeError: t._reverse is not a function
Build error at netlify the is this error happening in the node_modules\.vite\deps\jsonwebtoken.js file
This is a Vue 2 + Vite + Vuetify (v.2) project



Uncaught TypeError: t._reverse is not a function
    at index.1607bf8c.js:35:13236
    at index.1607bf8c.js:35:13634

Issue opened also in vite repo section (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/16385)
This is the code snippet where the issue is happening:
// node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/constants/der.js
var require_der = __commonJS({
  "node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/constants/der.js"(exports2) {
    var import_dist = __toESM(require_dist());
    var constants = require_constants();
    exports2.tagClass = {
      0: "universal",
      1: "application",
      2: "context",
      3: "private"
    };
    exports2.tagClassByName = constants._reverse(exports2.tagClass);
    exports2.tag = {
      0: "end",
      1: "bool",
      2: "int",
      3: "bitstr",
      4: "octstr",
      5: "null_",
      6: "objid",
      7: "objDesc",
      8: "external",
      9: "real",
      10: "enum",
      11: "embed",
      12: "utf8str",
      13: "relativeOid",
      16: "seq",
      17: "set",
      18: "numstr",
      19: "printstr",
      20: "t61str",
      21: "videostr",
      22: "ia5str",
      23: "utctime",
      24: "gentime",
      25: "graphstr",
      26: "iso646str",
      27: "genstr",
      28: "unistr",
      29: "charstr",
      30: "bmpstr"
    };
    exports2.tagByName = constants._reverse(exports2.tag);


Could you pls share the code snippet where you are encountering this error?

@Amaarockz this is the file path: node_modules\.vite\deps\jsonwebtoken.js

Focusing on the node_module code is the wrong idea.  Even if it was, no one can fix third party library code except the maintainers, so isn't suitable for Stack Overflow. However, something in your app is probably causing this code to run in a way that produces an error. We'll need to see how your app is configured to understand this downstream issue. See how to create an mcve and post enough dev code so that others can reproduce and understand the issue.

@yoduh... i have no idea on how and where i could put a reproducible ... it would require very specific configurations and sets of packages...

FYI, I ran into this issue on vite 2.x as well. I created a minimum reproduction for the problem (https://github.com/pward123/vite-issue-16385) that fails on vite@5.2.11. There's also a working rollup config on the prod-rollup branch of that same repo.
Since your issue was closed/locked due to vite 2 being end of support, but this is also happening on 5.2.11, I opened a new issue at https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/16697
